# AWS API Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a cloudformation template to create api gateway/resource/method/function on AWS platform, and also associated a lambda function to my api. Once I create the stack I get a url to hit my aws api. Whenever I hit this url, I get internal server error.
I am not sure what could be the reason, but if I toggle between 2 lambda functions from aws console for integration request and deploy, it starts working as expected.
I don't want to do it manually as deployment should be done at the time of stack creation.

Below is the template I used to create resources

```
Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'testing'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types: 
          - 'EDGE'

  ApigwResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      ParentId: !GetAtt RestApi.RootResourceId


  # lambda function
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Role: 'lambda_role'
      Handler: lambda_s3.lambda_handler
      Code:
        S3Bucket: { 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${S3Bucket}-S3AppsBucketId' }
        S3Key: 'lambda_source_code'
      Runtime: python3.7
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      FunctionName: !Sub 'lambda_function'

  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: PUT
      ResourceId: !Ref ApigwResource
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels: { 'application/json' : 'Empty' }
          StatusCode: 200
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        IntegrationHttpMethod: PUT
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        Uri: !Sub
          - 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations'
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn

  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - 'ApiGatewayMethod'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      StageName: !Ref Environment
```

Comment: Could you include your template? Otherwise no one can comment on what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, my api gateway didn't have permission to invoke lambda function. When I was toggling lambda functions manually, it used to provide necessary permissions to my api gateway thus this work around was working. I added below piece to my cloudformation template to make this work.

```
  ConfigLambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    DependsOn:
    - RestApi
    - LambdaFunction
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```